# Is there a way to edit a database datetime table to remove the seconds in each row?

Tags: sqlite

I have a database that currently saves the datetime data like this:

```
1|1|2022-01-02 06:00:00
2|1|2022-01-03 06:00:00
```

I want to remove the seconds from the data to look like this:

```
1|1|2022-01-02 06:00
2|1|2022-01-03 06:00
```

Is there a way to do this in `sqlite3`? As I write this I'm thinking about how I can do it using `python` which I do not think will be hard but I wanted to see if this could be done in `sqlite3` first.

I found this in my research but I'm not using mySQL. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/remove-seconds-from-time-field-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates you have in your table are actually strings and you can use the function `SUBSTR()` to strip off the last 3 chars:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET col = SUBSTR(col, 1, LENGTH(col) - 3);
```

Or, use the function `strftime()` function to get a string without seconds:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET col = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', col);
```

Change `col` to the column's name.

Comment: Did I do something wrong when I originally create the time in the first place? When creating the database I used `DateAndTime smalldatetime NOT NULL,` Should I have done something different?

Comment: @Funlamb in SQLite there is no Date or Datetime data type. You may use anything (even nothing) as a data type when defining a column, but actually there are only 5 storage classes in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html You can store dates as TEXT, or INTEGER for unix epochs or REAL for julian days.